# Dynamic Linq not returning right data

Tags: c#, json, linq

Im taking over an Excel parsing type app. It using jQuery Querybuilder on the frontend which builds up a nice where statement for us. The problem is my json query is not working.

PS. I NEED to use dynamic LINQ as that is what i get back from my jQuery Querybuilder

Essentially in an example, my Excel data looks like this:

```
[{"listOfCells":[{"column1":"Bob"},{"column2":"Dylan"},{"column3":"bob@awesome.com"},{"column4":"93208329"}],"rowNumber":0},{"listOfCells":[{"column1":"Rachel"},{"column2":"Best"},{"column3":"Rachel@awesome.com"},{"column4":"98798792"}],"rowNumber":1}]
```

My c# model looks a bit like this:

```
public class Table
    {
        public List<ListOfCells> listOfRows { get; set; }
        public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListOfCells
    {
        public string column0 { get; set; }
        public string column1 { get; set; }
        public string column2 { get; set; }
        public string column3 { get; set; }
        public string column4 { get; set; }
    }
```

I am able to deserialize the object:

`var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table>>(json);`

And run basic queries. I basically just look to give me all the rowNumbers that are a positive hit for the query:

```
var trial1 = obj.Select((row, j) => new { needed = row.listOfCells.Where("column1 = @0", "Bob").ToList(), count = j });

var rowsNeededAsIntArray = from rows in trial1
                           where rows.needed.Count > 0
                           select rows.count;
```

Give me what I need.

However this one doesnt:

```
var trial1 = obj.Select((row, j) => new { needed = row.listOfCells.Where("column1 = @0 AND ( column2 = @1 OR column2 = @2 )" ,"Bob", "Dylan", "Best").ToList(), count = j });

var rowsNeededAsIntArray = from rows in trial1
                           where rows.needed.Count > 0
                           select rows.count;
```

It should evaluate the OR first, and then the AND. But I get nothing back...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the && and || conditions.

You should use instead "And" and "Or" in your dynamic linq

Comment: No that wasn't it. Ive updated my edit though. Good suggestion